# Google Backup and Sync deletes files after syncing them

Tags: google-drive, synchronization, google-drive-shared-folder

There's a google drive shared folder that I wish to download on my drive.

The shared folder appears on my drive and is too big to be downloaded via a browser (271Go).

I use sync to get it on my computer. It synced.
Then, the tool goes into a frenzy of deleting all the files one by one, in the morning, my local folder is empty. I have the feeling it's trying to delete them remotely too (I set the option to : "never delete both"). Hopefully I have read only rights.

What is happening and how to prevent that ?